# Adding column to table makes the name appear without square brackets

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-schema, alter-table

I added a column to my table :

```
ALTER TABLE venues ADD decent BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

`.schema venues` returns :

```sql
CREATE TABLE [venues] (
   [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   [foursquare_id] TEXT NOT NULL,
   [pick] INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   [foursquare_data] TEXT NOT NULL,
   [lat] FLOAT NOT NULL,
   [lng] FLOAT NOT NULL,
   [name] TEXT NOT NULL,
   [closed] INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   [google_data] TEXT NOT NULL,
   [google_place_id] TEXT NOT NULL,
   [google_name] TEXT NOT NULL
, decent BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
```

Column I added does not have square brackets while all others do. What does this mean? Do I need to do this some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot-command `.schema venues` returns the `sql` column of the [Schema Table](https://sqlite.org/schematab.html) for the row that corresponds to the table `venues`.

The equivalent SQL statement would be:

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_schema WHERE name = 'venues';
```

As it is explained in [Interpretation Of The Schema Table](https://sqlite.org/schematab.html#interpretation_of_the_schema_table):

> The text in the sqlite_schema.sql column is a **copy of the original
> CREATE statement** text that created the object, except...

which means that if you used square brackets in all or some column names in the `CREATE TABLE` statement then this is what you get when you execute `.schema venues`.

If you add a new column, then its definition is added in the original `CREATE TABLE` statement inside the `sql` column **as it is written in the `ALTER TABLE` statement**.

If you want square brackets for all the column names then use them when you add the column:

```
ALTER TABLE venues ADD [decent] BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WIW1l2Vh).

Comment: May want to clarify square brackets are a quoting mechanism and not part of resulting identifier (unless enclosed by different quoting mechanism, like `"[name]"`).

Comment: OK. That clarifies. The original table was created by sqlite-utils so they may have added the brackets for everything.